# InputStream gives strange characters

Tags: java, character-encoding, inputstream

I am currently experimenting a very strange problem. In fact, I made a program some months ago and recently it starts not working so well so I look a bit deeper to find that there is something odd with `InputStream` output.

My program need to get some pages from internet but sometimes (because sometimes it works and sometimes it didn't... odd) I get strange characters like this :

[image]

Some other times I get the good html page but it's very rare.

The code is something like this (simple version)

```
InputStream is;
String inputLine;
if((is = URLConnectionReader.urlExists("xxxxurlxxxx")) != null)
{
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try
    {
        // First try
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        // Second try I don't have both in the code but both doesn't work 100% of the time. 
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        {
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("error");
    }
}
```

I put 2 in = new() because I tried both without success. What is really strange is that sometimes it will work 10 times in a row and after not work 10 times in a row...

```
public static InputStream urlExists(String url)
{
    try {
        URL site = new URL(url);
        try {
            return site.openStream();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            return null;
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: The first `BufferedReader` should have "UTF-8" as argument, not "UTF8".

Comment: What is `URLConnectionReader` and what sort of files are you downloading? Are they definitely text files? Are they definitely in UTF-8?

Comment: You are opening two `BufferedReader` wrapped `InputStreamReader`s on the same `InputStream`.  One with "UTF8" encoding, and the other with default platform encoding.  I don't think either of these things are what you want.  As pointed out elsewhere the encoding "UTF8" isn't really a valid name, but that's a bit of a moot point given that the `InputStreamReader` that actually gets used is the one opened with default platform encoding.  If you are using Java 7, use `StandardCharsets.UTF_8`, as the second arg, which has the benefit of not throwing an `UnsupportedEncodingException`.

Comment: Yes sorry "UTF-8" but the result is the same I get the same strange characters.
I just try to get the html of the page from the url.
I know that I open two but it's just to show what I tried I don't open 2 in real code. (I am currently using Java 6 because StandardCharsets doesn't exist for me)

Don't forget that it's not that it's not working at all, but that it's working sometimes and some other times I get the strange characters :s

Comment: you're either opening something that isn't a text file (like a jpeg or some such) or in a very different encoding than the one you specify.

Comment: That's what I thought that's why I tried to change the encoding but the result is same. Can't it comes from the website crypting some paging I don't know ? :s Because 30% of the times I get it well and 70% I get it bad with the same code.

Comment: *"30% of the times I get it well and 70% I get it bad"* Do you mean on the *same* page or *different* pages? IE do you mean *30% of the time reading a page works and 70% of the time reading that same page doesn't work* or do you mean *30% of pages work and 70% don't work*?

Comment: Yes on the same page, i get different results for the same url that's why it's truly odd for me. 70% don't work and 30% of time it works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I can reproduce the problem here, but with less frequency than you are seeing.  Using `tcpdump` to follow the stream, I believe the server has decided to send you a `gzip` compressed stream, rather than an uncompressed stream.

Here is the relevant header output from `tcpdump` in the failed case (first line wrapped for ease of reading).  The `Content-Encoding` is around `0x024A`:

```
    13:17:40.644241 IP r1.batoto.net.http > random.example.org.33779: Flags [P.],
      seq 1:604, ack 183, win 122,
      options [nop,nop,TS val 344850394 ecr 15945878], length 603
        // Some lines of headers removed
        0x0030:  0000 0000 4854 5450 2f31 2e31 2032 3030  ....HTTP/1.1.200
        0x0040:  204f 4b0d 0a53 6572 7665 723a 206e 6769  .OK..Server:.ngi
        0x0050:  6e78 2f31 2e32 2e37 0d0a 4461 7465 3a20  nx/1.2.7..Date:.
        0x0060:  4672 692c 2032 3920 4e6f 7620 3230 3133  Fri,.29.Nov.2013
        0x0070:  2030 323a 3437 3a33 3820 474d 540d 0a43  .02:47:38.GMT..C
        0x0080:  6f6e 7465 6e74 2d54 7970 653a 2074 6578  ontent-Type:.tex
        0x0090:  742f 6874 6d6c 3b63 6861 7273 6574 3d55  t/html;charset=U
        0x00a0:  5446 2d38 0d0a 5472 616e 7366 6572 2d45  TF-8..Transfer-E
        0x00b0:  6e63 6f64 696e 673a 2063 6875 6e6b 6564  ncoding:.chunked
        0x00c0:  0d0a 436f 6e6e 6563 7469 6f6e 3a20 6b65  ..Connection:.ke
        0x00d0:  6570 2d61 6c69 7665 0d0a 582d 506f 7765  ep-alive..X-Powe
        0x00e0:  7265 642d 4279 3a20 5048 502f 352e 342e  red-By:.PHP/5.4.
        0x00f0:  3135 0d0a 5365 742d 436f 6f6b 6965 3a20  15..Set-Cookie:.
        0x0100:  7365 7373 696f 6e5f 6964 3d32 3230 3433  session_id=22043
        0x0110:  3838 3431 3235 3739 3735 6566 6361 3333  8841257975efca33
        0x0120:  6462 3261 3264 6635 6665 643b 2070 6174  db2a2df5fed;.pat
        0x0130:  683d 2f3b 2064 6f6d 6169 6e3d 2e62 6174  h=/;.domain=.bat
        0x0140:  6f74 6f2e 6e65 743b 2068 7474 706f 6e6c  oto.net;.httponl
        0x0150:  790d 0a53 6574 2d43 6f6f 6b69 653a 2075  y..Set-Cookie:.u
        0x0160:  6167 656e 745f 6279 7061 7373 3d31 3b20  agent_bypass=1;.
        0x0170:  7061 7468 3d2f 3b20 646f 6d61 696e 3d2e  path=/;.domain=.
        0x0180:  6261 746f 746f 2e6e 6574 0d0a 5365 742d  batoto.net..Set-
        0x0190:  436f 6f6b 6965 3a20 636f 6d6d 656e 746d  Cookie:.commentm
        0x01a0:  6f64 7069 6473 3d64 656c 6574 6564 3b20  odpids=deleted;.
        0x01b0:  6578 7069 7265 733d 5468 752c 2030 312d  expires=Thu,.01-
        0x01c0:  4a61 6e2d 3139 3730 2030 303a 3030 3a30  Jan-1970.00:00:0
        0x01d0:  3120 474d 543b 2070 6174 683d 2f3b 2064  1.GMT;.path=/;.d
        0x01e0:  6f6d 6169 6e3d 2e62 6174 6f74 6f2e 6e65  omain=.batoto.ne
        0x01f0:  740d 0a43 6163 6865 2d43 6f6e 7472 6f6c  t..Cache-Control
        0x0200:  3a20 6d61 782d 6167 653d 3336 3030 0d0a  :.max-age=3600..
        0x0210:  4578 7069 7265 733a 2046 7269 2c20 3239  Expires:.Fri,.29
        0x0220:  204e 6f76 2032 3031 3320 3033 3a34 373a  .Nov.2013.03:47:
        0x0230:  3338 2047 4d54 0d0a 5072 6167 6d61 3a20  38.GMT..Pragma:.
        0x0240:  6e6f 2d63 6163 6865 0d0a 436f 6e74 656e  no-cache..Conten
        0x0250:  742d 456e 636f 6469 6e67 3a20 677a 6970  t-Encoding:.gzip
        0x0260:  0d0a 5661 7279 3a20 4163 6365 7074 2d45  ..Vary:.Accept-E
        0x0270:  6e63 6f64 696e 670d 0a58 2d43 6163 6865  ncoding..X-Cache
        0x0280:  3a20 4849 540d 0a0d 0a37 6639 360d 0a    :.HIT....7f96..
```

I'm not super expert in the HTTP protocol, but my guess is that `gzip` `Content-Encoding` shouldn't really be happening based on the request, and is maybe a server config issue.  Perhaps others more expert than me can comment based on the headers below:

```
    13:17:40.387277 IP random.example.org.33779 > r1.batoto.net.http:
      Flags [P.], seq 1:183, ack 1, win 229,
      options [nop,nop,TS val 15945878 ecr 344850135], length 182
        // Some lines of headers removed
        0x0030:  0000 0000 4745 5420 2f63 6f6d 6963 2f5f  ....GET./comic/_
        0x0040:  2f63 6f6d 6963 732f 6269 6c6c 792d 6261  /comics/billy-ba
        0x0050:  742d 7237 3734 2048 5454 502f 312e 310d  t-r774.HTTP/1.1.
        0x0060:  0a55 7365 722d 4167 656e 743a 204a 6176  .User-Agent:.Jav
        0x0070:  612f 312e 372e 305f 3435 0d0a 486f 7374  a/1.7.0_45..Host
        0x0080:  3a20 7777 772e 6261 746f 746f 2e6e 6574  :.www.batoto.net
        0x0090:  0d0a 4163 6365 7074 3a20 7465 7874 2f68  ..Accept:.text/h
        0x00a0:  746d 6c2c 2069 6d61 6765 2f67 6966 2c20  tml,.image/gif,.
        0x00b0:  696d 6167 652f 6a70 6567 2c20 2a3b 2071  image/jpeg,.*;.q
        0x00c0:  3d2e 322c 202a 2f2a 3b20 713d 2e32 0d0a  =.2,.*/*;.q=.2..
        0x00d0:  436f 6e6e 6563 7469 6f6e 3a20 6b65 6570  Connection:.keep
        0x00e0:  2d61 6c69 7665 0d0a 0d0a                 -alive....
```

Good news is that the fix is relatively simple.  Here is a `urlExists(...)` implementation that should work around the issue:

```java
      private static final Object GZIP_CONTENT_TYPE = "gzip";
    
      public static InputStream urlExists(String url)
      {
        try
        {
          URL site = new URL(url);
          try
          {
            URLConnection conn = site.openConnection();
            if (GZIP_CONTENT_TYPE.equals(conn.getContentEncoding()))
            {
              System.out.println("Using gzip stream");
              return new GZIPInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
            }
            System.out.println("Using uncompressed stream");
            return conn.getInputStream();
          }
          catch (IOException ex)
          {
            return null;
          }
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException ex)
        {
          return null;
        }
      }
```

Comment: Yes this solution seems to work very well thanks for your help. I am amazed by how you find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you see when you try to download binary files such as images, videos, .exe files etc. This is my best guess as to what is happening, without further pertinent details.

Comment: Actually here is one of the link I use http://www.batoto.net/comic/_/comics/billy-bat-r774 maybe it can help for further information.
When I just launch the program with just the code I gave you on this only page, I get it works for sometimes then it starts to give me the strange codes then it goes back to normal without any change in the code. The same code gives me different things depending on something I don't get.

Comment: But you haven't shown the whole source code or even told us what your code is doing.